# how to insert a child item in a treeview C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I want to add a child item in a TreeViewItem that was added previously. The problem with code like this:

[How to insert a child node in a TreeView Control in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838865/how-to-insert-a-child-node-in-a-treeview-control-in-wpf)

or with many other variations that I have tried to use like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= dataTreeview.Items.Count; i++)
        {
             TreeViewItem tempTVI = (TreeViewItem)dataTreeview.Items.GetItemAt(i); 
        }
```

is that I get an InvalidCastException exception because items(in the other stackoverflow question) or tempTVI are strings not TreeViewItem

I don't know why this is and I ran out of ideas.

If it helps I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community in preview.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't work with WPF controls in WinForms manner. WPF ones are intended to use with data binding. Please, read about ItemsControl, item containers, and data binding - there are many articles, blog posts and questions at SO.

Comment: I did looked how to do this before. The problem is that if one searches for what you have said finds only examples like this: TreeViewItem parent = new TreeViewItem("Parent"); TreeViewItem child = new TreeViewItem("Child"); parent.Items.Add(child); which again, is not what I am looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.aspx) in WPF is an extension of [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx). There are basically two ways to work with these controls, one that makes dynamically changing trees easy to manage, and one that makes completely static trees trivial to setup.

**Dynamic Trees**

The way `TreeView` was designed to be used is following the MVVM design pattern. Here is a quick example of this.

First, when working with MVVM, you always want some sort of base class for viewmodels that [implements property change notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.100).aspx). Here is the most basic example:

```
internal class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you need a class that represents the data for a single node in the tree. For example:

```
internal class Node : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<Node> mChildren;

    // Add all of the properties of a node here. In this example,
    // all we have is a name and whether we are expanded.
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private string _name;

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (_isExpanded != value)
            {
                _isExpanded = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private bool _isExpanded;

    // Children are required to use this in a TreeView
    public IList<Node> Children { get { return mChildren; } }

    // Parent is optional. Include if you need to climb the tree
    // from code. Not usually necessary.
    public Node Parent { get; private set; }

    public Node(Node parent = null)
    {
        mChildren = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
        IsExpanded = true;
        Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Now, create a viewmodel for your control with a collection of these nodes in it. In this example, the viewmodel is for the main window of the application:

```
internal class MainWindowVM : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<Node> mRootNodes;

    public IEnumerable<Node> RootNodes { get { return mRootNodes; } }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        mRootNodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>();

        // Test data for example purposes
        Node root = new Node() { Name = "Root" };
        Node a = new Node(root) { Name = "Node A" };
        root.Children.Add(a);
        Node b = new Node(root) { Name = "Node B" };
        root.Children.Add(b);
        Node c = new Node(b) { Name = "Node C" };
        b.Children.Add(c);
        Node d = new Node(b) { Name = "Node D" };
        b.Children.Add(d);
        Node e = new Node(root) { Name = "Node E" };
        root.Children.Add(e);
        mRootNodes.Add(root);
    }
}
```

Finally, create the `TreeView` instance and set it up to use your data. In this example, the `TreeView` is the only thing in the main application window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTreeViewExample.MainWindow"
        x:ClassModifier="internal"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTreeViewExample"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVM />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <TreeView
        Margin="10"
        ItemsSource="{Binding RootNodes}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style
                TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
                <!-- Could also put IsSelected here if we needed it in our Node class -->
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate
                DataType="{x:Type local:Node}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <!-- Can build any view we want here to be used for each node -->
                <!-- Simply displaying the name in a text block for this example -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Window>
```

Once you have this setup, all you have to do from now on is manipulate the data in your viewmodel, and the `TreeView` will automatically update to reflect those changes. This way, you never need to manipulate the control directly.

Here is the resulting view:

[image: Screenshot]

**Static Trees**

If the entire tree is known ahead of time and will never change, you can set it up pretty simply like this:

```
<TreeView
    x:Name="mTreeView"
    Margin="10">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Root">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Node A" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Node B">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Node C" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Node D" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Node E" />
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

The problem with this approach is that when you want to modify the tree programmatically, it becomes hard to manage because you have to deal with the `TreeView` itself. However, it is doable from a code-behind. For example, if I want to add a new child node under "Node C" called "New Node", I could do something like this:

```
((TreeViewItem)((TreeViewItem)((TreeViewItem)mTreeView.Items[0]).Items[1]).Items[0]).Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "New Node" });
```

Working this way gets messy though. Since we don't have a parallel representation of the tree in data, we have to keep accessing things through the control and casting them.

**Some Other Setup**

Looking at your question, it looks like you are not following either of these approaches, but instead have a TreeView that is setup basically like this:

```
<TreeView>
    <sys:String>Node A</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Node B</sys:String>
</TreeView>
```

So, you have a `TreeView` full of strings. Internally, an `ItemsControl` can take any object and wrap it in an item container. `TreeView` will wrap those strings in `TreeViewItem` instances. However, the items are still stored as strings, and accessing `TreeView.Items` will return the strings that you added.

Getting the `TreeViewItem` associated with an arbitrary item in a `TreeView` is actually fairly difficult because you have to get the containers for each item at the root level, then dig into each of those and get containers for their items, and so on all the way through the tree until you find the item you are looking for.

You can find an example for how to lookup item containers [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407130(v=vs.100).aspx). Note that you cannot use [virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716882(v=vs.100).aspx) in your `TreeView` in order for this to work reliably. Also, I would recommend against working this way because you are making things harder on yourself.

Comment: I have another question though: how can I get the index of the children when the user clicks on one?
What I mean by that is:
click Node A -> get 0
click Node B -> get 1
click Node E -> get 2
I don't use a three level data so I do not care about C and D
p.s. this is very very important

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer eventually. Thanks again Xavier

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot the  tags?
If you have the following in your xaml file:

```
    <TreeView x:Name="MyTreeView">
        <TreeViewItem>Hello</TreeViewItem>
        World
    </TreeView>
```

And the following in the code-behind:

```
var a = MyTreeView.Items.GetItemAt(0) as string;
var b = MyTreeView.Items.GetItemAt(0) as TreeViewItem;
var c = MyTreeView.Items.GetItemAt(1) as string;
var d = MyTreeView.Items.GetItemAt(1) as TreeViewItem;
```

Variables a and d will be null whereas b will be a TreeViewItem and c will be a string.

Comment: that gives me a NullRecerenceException

Comment: Did you surround your items in <TreeViewItem> tags?

Comment: I can't do that. They are not added in xaml code. They are added with a form like structure. So, this is not an option

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `String` because that is what the source of the `TreeView` must have been bound to.

Using this method allows you to iterate over the items and retrieve the `TreeViewItem` containers that they are inside:

```
 List<TreeViewItem> GetChildren(TreeViewItem parent)
    {
      List<TreeViewItem> children = new List<TreeViewItem>();

      if (parent != null)
      {
        foreach (var item in parent.Items)
        {
          TreeViewItem child = item as TreeViewItem;

          if (child == null)
          {
            child = parent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(child) as TreeViewItem;
          }

          children.Add(child);
        }
      }

      return children;
    }
```

Please notice that they check if the TreeViewItem is null after casting it.  This is good practice as it prevents the null reference exception from crashing your application if something does happen to go wrong.

source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/595f0c84-01e7-4534-b73b-704b41713fd5/traversing-the-children-of-a-treeviewitem

Comment: I believe I have not asked my question very clearly. What I want is to get the parent, not its children. Better I am wandering how to iterate through treeview parents in order to be able to add a child to it if its name is the correct one