# Populate Treeview with SQL Databases and its Tables

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, database, treeview

How do I populate Treeview with checkboxes with all the Databases and its tables in a Server using C# WPF Application?

```
 -Server 1----------------      
-        - Database1     -
-          -- Table1     -
-          -- Table2     -
-          -- Table3     -
-        - Database2     -
-          -- Table1     -
-          -- Table2     -
-          -- Table3     -
--------------------------
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Also, use [`SHOW DATABASES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-databases.html) to retrieve the list of databases and [`SHOW TABLES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html) to get the list of tables from the DB then it's just a [matter of adding them to the treeview](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30953599/162671)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to firstly return a list of all databases that are useful.

```
SELECT name FROM master..sysdatabases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb');
```

Then for each database get a list of tables

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
```

Then find examples of how to populate TreeViews in WPF.

[maybe this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415037/populate-treeview-from-list-of-file-paths-in-wpf)

Then ......
Write the code!